# creating real time graph using mysql data and highchart

Tags: php, ajax, highcharts

I have a records.values table in myDB.When new data is inserted into this table I want to change the graph.I used php and highchart but there is nothing can be seen from browser.What is wrong thing in my code.I use ubuntu 14.04.

### index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("/home/cea/Desktop/deneme/data.php", function(json) {

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'REgion vs. type',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Amount'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: json
            });
        });

    });

});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

### data.php

accessing database values

```
 <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","963369");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else print "connected!";
mysql_select_db("records", $con);

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT region FROM records.values");
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'Region';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
    $rows['data'][] = $r['region'];
}

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT type FROM records.values");
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'Type';
while($rr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows1['data'][] = $rr['type'];
}

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM records.values");
$rows2 = array();
$rows2['name'] = 'Value';
while($rrr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows2['data'][] = $rrr['value'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);
array_push($result,$rows2);


print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

What is the missing point in here? **I just started to learn php and highcharts. Thank you..

Comment: Well you are just getting the data when the document is ready...? You'd have to check for updates regularly to ever see it update.

Comment: @Halvor Strand I know but I have already ready data.But I cannot see graph in my browser.How can I fix this. I have ever used PHP before.

Comment: You can't see the graph? Do you have an error in your Javascript console?

Comment: There is no error shown? Just blank screen..

Comment: How your JSON does it look like ?